# Record video with a size of 480 * 480 px in android?

Tags: android, video-capture, vine

I have built a module similar to vine app video recording. But I am not able to make the video size to 480x480 px . Is there any way to do that. Thanks

Comment: what are you using for recording ? tell us what have you done so far

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: `asked Feb 4 '14` - so it seems you struggle finding the answer for almost 4 years :)

Comment: sorry pals I don't have any code regarding this. I asked this question for a project of mine which never happened as I wasn't able to find a optimal solution at that time.

Answer (score 1):

The Android camera has a limited list of available sizes for the camera. So we need to select best camera size and select sub image(480x480) from the original camera image. 
For example on my HTC one m8 I have this sizes for the camera:

1. 1920x1088
2. 1920x1080
3. 1808x1080
4. ....
5. 720x480
6. 640x360
7. 640x480
8. 576x432
9. 480x320
10. 384x288
11. 352x288
12. 320x240
13. 240x160
14. 176x144

You can retrieve list of available size by use [getSupportedPreviewSizes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes()) method.

```
public Camera mCamera;//Your camera instance
public List<Camera.Size> cameraSizes;
private final int CAMERA_IMAGE_WIDTH = 480;
private final int CAMERA_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 480;
...

cameraSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes()
```

After that, you need to find most suitable camera size and set preview size for the camera.

```
Camera.Size findBestCameraSize(int width, int height){
  Camera.Size bestSize = cameraSizes.get(0);
  int minimalArea = bestSize.height * bestSize.width;
  for(int i = 1;i < cameraSizes.size();i++){
    Camera.Size size = cameraSizes.get(i);

    int area = size.height * size.width;
    if(size.width < width || size.height < height){
      continue;
    }

    if(area < minimalArea){
      bestSize = size;
      minimalArea = area;
    }
  }
  return bestSize;
}

...
SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    //Do something
  }

  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                             int format, int width,
                             int height) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size size = findBestCameraSize(CAMERA_IMAGE_WIDTH, CAMERA_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    if(mCamera != null){
      mCamera.startPreview();
    }
  }

  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Do something
  }
  };
```

After setup camera size, we need to get sub image from result bitmap, from the camera. You need put this code where you receive a bitmap picture(Usually I use an OpenCV library and matrixes for better performance).

```
Bitmap imageFromCamera = //here ve receive image from camera.
Camera.Size size = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
int x = (size.width - CAMERA_IMAGE_WIDTH)/2;
int y = (size.height - CAMERA_IMAGE_HEIGHT)/2;
Bitmap resultBitmap = null;
if(x < 0 || y < 0){
   resultBitmap = imageFromCamera;
}else{
   resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageFromCamera, x, y, CAMERA_IMAGE_WIDTH, CAMERA_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The video capture resolution for android are limited to the native resolutions supported by the camera.

You can try using a 3rd party library for video post processing. So you can crop or re-scale the video captured by the camera.

I am using this one

[android-gpuimage-videorecording](https://github.com/westbrett/android-gpuimage-videorecording)

and it works quite well.